# Continue with the output from a previous chunk in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to use/continue with the output from a previous chunk in rmarkdown as follows:

````
```{r one}
x <- 1
print(x)
```

```{r two}
x <- x + 10
print(x)
```

```{r three, use.output.from = "one"}
x <- x * 2
print(x)
```
````

Here, the last chunk should work with x as created in the chunk with label "one". In other words, chunk "three" should print "2" instead of "22".

I have tried to set

````
```{r three, dependson = "one"}
print(x)
```
````

which doesn't work as it prints "22" instead of "2". Also

````
```{r three,ref.label = "one"}
x <- x * 2
print(x)
```
````

does not work and prints "1" instead of "2" (and it performs the entire chunk "one" again in full).

Is there a chunk option that allows me to call `x` as outputted from "one" rather than from "two" in chunk "three"? Perhaps by caching x in "one" and then calling that specific cache? Or there may be another approach. Ideally, it would work something like "exercise.setup" in learnr (I don't know how that works, but it doesn't appear to execute "one" again).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `local` to declare a new local scope so the global variables will not be changed.

````
```{r one}
x <- 1
print(x)
```

```{r two}
local({
x <- x + 10
print(x)
})
```

```{r three, use.output.from = "one"}
x <- x * 2
print(x)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. I would prefer to access x from "one" directly, just in case I forget to add local() in the various chunks that might be added (now and in the future) between "one" and "three", but this is a useful solution for short rmarkdown documents.